# Run Windows program in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, exe

How would you use Node.js to run a program in the form of?:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\TechSmith\Camtasia Studio 8\CamRecorder.exe
```

If this is possible than I would like to know how to send commands like F9 and F10 to start and stop the program. F9 and F10 are already the programs' hotkeys. I have learned about exec(), but I see that it is limited in memory that it can work with. Could someone point me in the correct direction, so I can experiment and learn and come back if I need more help? Thanks

Comment: I don't think it will be possible to send commands from nodejs to a program very easily - requires some pretty in depth knowledge of Windows internals - I see no memory limitations with exec besides the stdin/out/err buffers - you probably wont get any stdout/err from a GUI program anyway

Comment: Thanks that is helpful!

Comment: Is there a way just to launch the program?